# Pandas group like values together and sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
Index    Quarter    Average    Location
0        2000Q1     1234       London
1        2000Q1     5678       Brighton
...      ...        ...        ...
99       2018Q3     9876       London
100      2018Q3     9987       Brighton
```

To work out the start of a recession I must first group these quarters together using the method:

```
df = df.groupby(['Quarter','Average']).sum()
```

However this does not return what I intend. I wish for all the matching quarter average to be summed together, giving me Q1, Q2, Q3 average.

Where abouts am I going wrong.

Comment: `df.groupby('Quarter')['Average'].agg('sum')` might be what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think that returns a dataframe, which I will need to do some further processing to find the start and end quarters of a recession.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you:

```
df.groupby('Quarter').agg('sum')
```

Comment: Or `df.groupby('Quarter').sum()['Average']`